# Clarification for set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

We know that every nonzero integer is uniquely given by $p n$ where $p$ is either $1$ or $-1$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Given this, my question is about expressing the set of integers in the following way.

Would it be sensical to write something as the following?

$$\mathbb{Z}_\text{nonzero}=\{pn\ |\ p\in \{1,-1\}, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
How about
$$\mathbb{Z}_\text{nonzero}=\{m\ |\ m=pn \text{ where } p\in \{1,-1\} \text{ and } n\in \mathbb{N}\}?$$

My concern is that when write $\{pn\ |\ \cdots$, I called $pn$ without defining what they are. Compare this to the case of the set of even natural numbers $A=\{n\in\mathbb{N} \ | \ 2 \text{ divides } n\}$, where $n$ is defined as a natural number from the very first place of calling it.

Comment: I'd say that both ways are OK.

Comment: I think writing $\{pn\mid p = \pm 1, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is interpreted as a shorthand notation to the second option you gave. I wouldn't mind it and have seen it numerous times.

Comment: Thanks for both of the answer! I think it may be okay given that the first option is a shorthand notation for the second option, and second option is logically sensible (we can define something as $\cdots \ x \ $where $x$ is $\cdots$). Thank you!